# What type of usability test to perform on android app?

Tags: usability, mobile, android

What is the best app test type to perform on a native mobile application? Currently I'm developing a tourism Android application, and so far I've decided to perform A/B testing with questionnaires, and a propitiatory click/time logging API to monitor user scenario walkthoroughs, but the client requires at least two types of tests to be performed.
I thought about card sorting, but there isn't much information architecture in my application, like on a website.

What other test could I perform to get some tangible results?

I'm searching for a second type of test to perform, for ex. card-sorting, or something else that would prove that the prototype that I'm making is user friendly.

Comment: Maybe I didn't state my question clearly. My client needs two types of tests to be done. I've decided on A/B Cognitive Walk-through tests (/w questionnaires), and now I'm searching for a second type of test to perform, for ex. card-sorting, or something else that would prove that the prototype that I'm making is user friendly.

Answer (score 1):

For examples of some app specific questions and user flows, I recommend looking at [this paper which talks about usability testing of specific android applications](http://sdsu-dspace.calstate.edu/bitstream/handle/10211.10/3556/Alluri_Aruna.pdf?sequence=1). To quote an excerpt from the paper

> **4.1.2 Test Questions and Testing with Users**
>
> 1. **Get the result of (189 + 2874) * (408 + 521)**. The motivation behind this question is  lack of visibility of braces in portrait
>      mode. To calculate the above expression, user  either has to change
>      the view to landscape mode or advanced panel in the portrait  mode to
>      find the braces. Before the test session users were made familiar with
>      portrait  and landscape modes in the phone but one out of five users
>      (smart phone user) was  able to figure out to use the landscape mode
>      to enter the braces. The rest of the  participants could not think of
>      switching to landscape or advanced panel to enter the  braces. All of
>      them used portrait mode by remembering the result of the first part to
>      complete the whole expression.
> 2. **Get the result of the following expression**: 2 (tan(45))/log 10. The motivation behind  this question is the ability to slide
>      horizontally to switch between the panels from  basic to advance.
>      There are two ways to go to advanced panel, sliding horizontally or 
>      selecting advanced panel from menu options in which the first one is
>      easier but there  is no visibility for the user to find this feature.
>      The more visible way for the user is by  going to menu options and
>      selects the advanced panel but this makes it harder for the   user as
>      it requires switching to advanced panel several times. Only one
>      participant  among all could learn about the sliding feature to
>      accomplish the task.

With regards to general usability testing guidelines for android apps, I recommend looking at these suggestions. To quote the [article](http://help.utest.com/testers/crash-courses/usability/mobile-testing-android-usability-101)

> **Touch**
>
> - Sidebars are not easy to use on touchscreens.
> - Fingerprints are more visible on darker backgrounds.
> - There must be a way to go back or undo an action, as touching the wrong item is done quickly.
> - The full screen should be used.
> - Common operations directly visible on screen.
> - Minimize keyboard input.
>
> **Icons & Buttons**
>    - Buttons should have the right size and be suitable to big fingers.
>    - Buttons in the same place of the screen to avoid confusion.
>    - Natural and consistent icons.
>    - Buttons that have the same function should have the same color.
>
> **Menu**
>
> - Contextual menus are used very often, it should not be overloaded because it has to be used quickly.
>
> **Text**
>
> - Keep text simple and clear.
> - Short sentences and paragraphs are better readable.
> - The usage of headers will make a text better readable.
> - Bullets for lists will make a text better readable.
> - Typing text in a textbox should start with an uppercase letter.
> - The font size should be big enough, not too big and not too small.
>
> **Messages**
>
> - Confirmation messages should be avoided, a click performs the action directly.
> - When the app starts downloading a lot of data, the user should be warned.

Lastly I strongly recommend looking at the [Human Interface guidelines for Android](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) to ensure you can define the appropriate usability test attributes as per the proposed guidelines.